# Android Dialog - Custom background instead of dimming or blurring

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have created my own custom dialog and it works fine but I want to change dimmed background to a custom pattern (for example an image file or a xml shape). How can I achieve that?
Note that I do not want to change intensity of dimming but I just want, this dimming be replaced with a pattern

Comment: can you post image showing what you want to achieve?

Comment: @GopalRao I found a workaround for my problem (I've posted it as an answer) but I am worry about it's efficiency, is it good? if no can you please offer me a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem, I derived this from @vipul mittal answer,
I should set dialog theme as following:

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

With this theme my dialog will be:

- **full screen** because `windowIsFloating` is set to `false`
- **surrounding area is fully transparent** because `windowBackground` is set to `@android:color/transparent`

Now I should wrap my dialog xml layout contents with a wrapper that plays surrounding area role, in this case I have picked `FrameLayout` for this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_back"> <!-- this is surrounding area drawable -->

    <!-- dialog contents goes here -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of my final dialog:
[image]

Comment: hmmm... nice. similar Idea I have :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change dialog theme to:

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In custom dialog when you call super call this:

```
public CustomDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, But this will change the background of the dialog not the surrounding area of the dialog

Comment: try it this will change the background of the dialog. just change the android:windowBackground to what you you want

Comment: I do not want to change the dialog background. Instead I want to change the pattern of surrounding area. Also you have set the `android:windowIsFloating` to `false` that stretch the dialog to fit whole screen while I don't want a full screen dialog

Comment: set height and width of the dialog as wrap_content and it wont fill the complete screen.